# Wordpress Plugin: JavaScript Loading before Page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Creating my first Wordpress Plugin and having an issue with JavaScript loading.

I'm defining a Class which runs several functions that include JavaScript via `wp_enqueue_script`.

**Here is a sample `JS` file Demonstrating Problem:**

```
//The alert will fire
alert('javascript is firing');
// This will return an error saying 
//Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("ng-app", "app");
```

**`plugin.php:`**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Wordpress Plugin
Plugin URI: http://www.wordpressplugin.io
Description: A Wordpress Plugin
Author: Me
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.me.com
*/

define('Wordpress Plugin', '1');

class wordpressPlugin {

function __init(){
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'angularScripts'));
}

function angularScripts(){
      wp_enqueue_script('app', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__).'js/app.js',array('jquery'), null, false);
}



//Create instance of class
$wpNG = new wordpressPlugin();
// Activate Plugin
add_action( 'init', array( $wpNG, '__init' ), 1000 );
?>
```

**`app.js`**

```
alert('hello');
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("ng-app", "app");
```

The alert will fire but the `document.getElements` will not run and return an error of undefined. But, if I wrap this within a `window.onload` function the `document.getElements` will run fine. Doing a `window.onload` is not the desirable.

How does the `JavaScript` need to be set up to run without needing `window.onload`?

Comment: Using window.onload is the right way to do this. What makes you say it's undesirable?

Comment: I'm going to have to load in AngularJS and other resources. Noticed that scripts weren't running correctly.

Comment: Replace `add_action( 'init', array( $wpNG, '__init' ), 1000 );` with `add_action( 'wp_head', array( $wpNG, '__init' ), 1000 );` then check and let me know.

Comment: Try like [https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). And one more thing if you replied to me then tag me so i can get that you replied me.

Comment: @KaushaMehta would I need to use something like `add_filter()` to hook into the JS functions? If the file is present, feels like it's not getting fired correctly.

Comment: Why you want to use `add_filter()`?, For enqueue wordpress provide `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.